# No module named PiCamera

Tags: python-3

Trying to run a python program in a vm (virtual environment) with the picamera module, i'm running it in the vm because i have other modules there like OpenCV.
When running the program i get the error: 
   " ImportError: No module named 'picamera' "
Does anyone know where the picamera module is installed or the location, so i can move it.
Btw, the module imports correctly when i run the program outside of the vm. And i can't run outside of the vm, i HAVE to find a way to get the picamera module to work in the vm.

Comment: this is really a python question, not an RPi question.   ..... this may help ... https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments

Answer (score 1):

Once you've activated your vm, install picamera in the usual way. It should work - let us see what you're doing (commands, etc), and we'll try to help.